# How to add new npm dependency to kotlin?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

While going through Kotlin/js [tutorial](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Building%20Web%20Applications%20with%20React%20and%20Kotlin%20JS/02_Setting_up) I tried to replace deprecated `react-youtube-lite` libarary with `react-youtube`, but in browser console I get error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I updated the build.gradle.kts:

```
dependencies {
...
    //Video Player (chapter 7)
    implementation(npm("react-youtube-lite", "1.5.0"))
    implementation(npm("react-youtube", "9.0.3"))
...
}
```

I see that yarn.lock was successfully updated on browserRun task, the new `react-youtube` is there.

I created the new component, but using it gives the error above:

```
@file:JsModule("react-youtube")
@file:JsNonModule

import react.*

@JsName("ReactYoutube")
external val ReactYoutube: ComponentClass<ReactYoutubeProps>

external interface ReactYoutubeProps : Props {
    var videoId: String?
    var opts: Any
}
```

Example:
https://github.com/beshur/kotlin-confexplorer/pull/1

Comment: I needed to use `@JsName("default")`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as one of my friends suggested, I needed to use `@JsName("default")` to use the default export from `react-youtube` package.